# Laplace Transform with initial value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> Use the Laplace transform to solve the following initial value
>   problem:
>
> $$y'' + y = 2t$$
>
> with $y(\pi/4) = \pi / 2 $ and $y'(\pi/4) = 2 - \sqrt{2}$.

I understand this type of problems but with initial values for $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$ .. How could I solve it with $y(\pi /4)$ and $y'(\pi /4)$ ?

Comment: Try this site http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/IVPWithLaplace.aspx partway down is a segment on nonzero initial time

Comment: @Triatticus I will try it .. Thank you

Comment: I hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laplace-transforming both sides of $y'' + y = 2t$,

$$s^2 Y (s) - y_0 s - v_0 + Y (s) = \frac{2}{s^2}$$

Hence,

$$Y (s) = y_0 \left(\frac{s}{s^2 + 1}\right) + (v_0 - 2)\left(\frac{1}{s^2 + 1}\right) + \frac{2}{s^2}$$

Taking the inverse Laplace transform,

$$y (t) = y_0 \cos (t) + (v_0 - 2) \sin (t) + 2 t$$

From the conditions $y(\pi /4) = \pi / 2 $ and $y'(\pi /4) = 2- \sqrt{2}$, we get

$$y_0 + v_0 = 2 \qquad  \qquad \qquad y_0 - v_0 = 2$$

Thus, $y_0 = 2$ and $v_0 = 0$, and

$$y (t) = 2 \cos (t) - 2 \sin (t) + 2 t$$